# serving all static content of a website locally

Tags: firefox, browser, static-content

I want to run a local server on which I can save all the static files of websites, when I run the website I want it to dynamically chaneg the urls to get static content from my server. Is there a firefox plugin or some other tool to do this easily?

Answer (score 0):

I've used HTTrack Website Copier for this type of task before, it's at httrack.com and it's free.